# Can’t open Device Manager in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, internet-explorer, speakers, device-manager

So lately my PC stopped recognizing my speakers. I searched for a solution, and every tip lead me to using the Device Manager.

When I try to open it, it says that the MMC (Microsoft Management Console) won’t run with a version of Internet Explorer older than 5.5 – even though I have version 11.

I even reinstalled Internet Explorer, and still it doesn’t work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround for this issue where you can create a string entry (REG_SZ) in regedit under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer** called Version with the value 6.0.0.0

Comment: Please provide a reference for this solution.

Comment: @kloneman, I am not so good with computers, I found the file svcVersion, but what exactly am I supposed to do with it? The value of it is 11.0.9600.16428. How do I change it? And thanks for helping me.

Comment: So I changed the value to 6.0.0.0 and it does nothing.